# How to prevent "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0" when the expected argument is `undefined`?

Tags: typescript

**Typescript Version: 2.6.2**

I'm trying to make redux a bit more typesafe than what you get with the out of the box typedefs while also reducing some of the boilerplate. I think I'm *really* close to what I'm looking for - with one exception. Here's what I've got:

```
// Action definiton from redux typedefs
interface Action {
  type: any;
}

// Action type using generics
// T is intended to be a string literal
// P is optional, so it defaults to undefined
interface TypedAction<T extends string, P = undefined> extends Action {
    readonly type: T;
    readonly payload: P;
}

// Function for generating the most common type of action creator
// Takes a TypedAction as its generic arg and uses that to infer
// what is required as the payload in the returned action creator
function makeActionCreator<T extends TypedAction<any, any>>(
    type: T['type'],
): (p: T['payload']) => T {
    return payload => ({ type, payload } as T);
}

//=================
// Example usage //
//=================

interface EmailPasswordCredential {
    readonly email: string;
    readonly password: string;
}

enum SignUpActionType {
    executeSignUp = 'SignUp/executeSignUp',
    reportSuccess = 'SignUp/reportSuccess',
    reportError = 'SignUp/reportError',
}

////
// Action Types
////

// Sign-up action
// requires an email and password to be specified
type ExecuteSignUpAction = TypedAction<
    SignUpActionType.executeSignUp,
    EmailPasswordCredential
>;

// Success action
// Doesn't need a payload
type ReportSignUpSuccessAction = TypedAction<SignUpActionType.reportSuccess>;

// Error action
// Fired when something didn't work (like a 400)
// Error is passed back as the payload
type ReportSignUpErrorAction = TypedAction<SignUpActionType.reportError, Error>;

////
// Action Creators
////

const signUp = makeActionCreator<ExecuteSignUpAction>(
    SignUpActionType.executeSignUp,
);

const reportSignUpSuccess = makeActionCreator<ReportSignUpSuccessAction>(
    SignUpActionType.reportSuccess,
);

const reportSignUpError = makeActionCreator<ReportSignUpErrorAction>(
    SignUpActionType.reportSuccess, // because of the generic - this correctly errors from the type mismatch
);

// the real problem:

// this correctly errors, an EmailPasswordCredential is required
signUp(); 

// this, however, should be allowed. 
//the missing argument is "undefined", which is what we are passing, by passing nothing.
reportSignUpSuccess();

// this fixes the type error, but feels unnecessary
reportSignUpSuccess(undefined);
```

[You can see the full example with syntax highlighting and inline errors here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Action%20definiton%20from%20redux%20typedefs%0D%0Ainterface%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Action%20type%20using%20generics%0D%0A%2F%2F%20T%20is%20intended%20to%20be%20a%20string%20literal%0D%0A%2F%2F%20P%20is%20optional%2C%20so%20it%20defaults%20to%20undefined%0D%0Ainterface%20TypedAction%3CT%20extends%20string%2C%20P%20%3D%20undefined%3E%20extends%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20type%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20payload%3A%20P%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Function%20for%20generating%20the%20most%20common%20type%20of%20action%20creator%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Takes%20a%20TypedAction%20as%20its%20generic%20arg%20and%20uses%20that%20to%20infer%0D%0A%2F%2F%20what%20is%20required%20as%20the%20payload%20in%20the%20returned%20action%20creator%0D%0Afunction%20makeActionCreator%3CT%20extends%20TypedAction%3Cany%2C%20any%3E%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20T%5B'type'%5D%2C%0D%0A)%3A%20(p%3A%20T%5B'payload'%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20payload%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%20type%2C%20payload%20%7D%20as%20T)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Example%20usage%20%2F%2F%0D%0A%2F%2F%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20EmailPasswordCredential%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20email%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20password%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aenum%20SignUpActionType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20executeSignUp%20%3D%20'SignUp%2FexecuteSignUp'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reportSuccess%20%3D%20'SignUp%2FreportSuccess'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reportError%20%3D%20'SignUp%2FreportError'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Action%20Types%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Sign-up%20action%0D%0A%2F%2F%20requires%20an%20email%20and%20password%20to%20be%20specified%0D%0Atype%20ExecuteSignUpAction%20%3D%20TypedAction%3C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SignUpActionType.executeSignUp%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20EmailPasswordCredential%0D%0A%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Success%20action%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Doesn't%20need%20a%20payload%0D%0Atype%20ReportSignUpSuccessAction%20%3D%20TypedAction%3CSignUpActionType.reportSuccess%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Error%20action%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Fired%20when%20something%20didn't%20work%20(like%20a%20400)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Error%20is%20passed%20back%20as%20the%20payload%0D%0Atype%20ReportSignUpErrorAction%20%3D%20TypedAction%3CSignUpActionType.reportError%2C%20Error%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Action%20Creators%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20signUp%20%3D%20makeActionCreator%3CExecuteSignUpAction%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SignUpActionType.executeSignUp%2C%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reportSignUpSuccess%20%3D%20makeActionCreator%3CReportSignUpSuccessAction%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SignUpActionType.reportSuccess%2C%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reportSignUpError%20%3D%20makeActionCreator%3CReportSignUpErrorAction%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SignUpActionType.reportSuccess%2C%20%2F%2F%20because%20of%20the%20generic%20-%20this%20correctly%20errors%20beacuse%20of%20the%20type%20mismatch%0D%0A)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20the%20real%20problem%3A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20correctly%20errors%2C%20a%20EmailPasswordCredential%20is%20required%0D%0AsignUp()%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%2C%20however%2C%20should%20be%20allowed.%20the%20missing%20argument%20is%20%22undefined%22%2C%20which%20is%20what%20we%20are%20passing%2C%20by%20passing%20nothing.%0D%0AreportSignUpSuccess()%3B)

Is there something I can do to fix the "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0" problem? Am I setting up `TypedAction` weird by specifying undefined as the default?

Answer (score 0):

Use `void` instead of undefined.